# Find all conversation items, including sent items, with EWS

Tags: email, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In Exchange 2010, the awesome operation `FindConversation` was introduced. However, this operation only lets you specify one folder to find conversations in, so when you use `FindConversation` on e.g. the `inbox`-folder, you will not get the parts of the conversation that you sent yourself (since they reside in the `sentitems`-folder).

To mitigate this, I plucked out all the unique `conversationIds` I got from the `FindConversation`-operation, and did a regular `FindItem` with a big `Restriction`-clause asking for items that belonged to any of these conversations. This gave me the error: ***The property cannot be used with this type of restriction***.

So then I asked for the `Extended Property 0x3013` of the first item in each conversation, which is some other type of `ConversationId` (?), and used the same method described above. This actually worked! However, this was very slow, and pretty much ruined the great end user experience a simple `FindConversation`-operation followed by a `GetItem`-operation gave.

Is there a better way to get the entire conversation (the user's own mail included) than described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking out the `ConversationTopic` of each conversation (which you get in the `FindConversation`-operation), and created a large `Rectriction` and asked for items in the `sentitems`-folder that had any of these topics as their own with a `Finditem`-operation. Then when I got the response, I mapped each item to the conversation they belonged to. This way I did not have to do 2 `FindItem`-operations, and it went very fast.